# How to remove unnecessary/superfluous log lines from ./gradlew test result

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradlew

When I run `./gradlew test`, I am interested in test results only. However, gradlew reports ~20 extra lines with different information about documentation/ where to get help.

This is not necessary because I know the reason of the failure was because the test failed.

Here is an example:

```
$ ./gradlew :mqtt:test                 
Type-safe dependency accessors is an incubating feature.

>>>> RETAIN

> Task :mqtt:test

MqttTest > subscribesToAllTopicsAfterConnect FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: Assertion failed
        at MqttTest.subscribesToAllTopicsAfterConnect(MqttTest.kt:43)

---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Results: FAILURE (2 tests, 1 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped)  |
---------------------------------------------------------------

2 tests completed, 1 failed

> Task :mqtt:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

>>>> RETAIN

>>>> UNNECESSARY

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mqtt:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/tonis/workspace/java/charon-android-automotive/mqtt/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date


>>>> UNNECESSARY
```

I have embedded the part that is not necessary with >>>> UNNECESSARY

Comment: This is not the report, it is simply stdout.  Typically you can configure a test framework to generate a report, and I'd look into that if I were you.  I'd remove the java, kotlin gradle gradlew tags and add mqtt.

Comment: The output is very noisy but you do have `See the report at: file:///Users/tonis/workspace/java/charon-android-automotive/mqtt/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
`

Comment: I dont want to open a web page to see the results. My shell output already shows the stacktrace and failed tests.